# How to change title (tooltip) from kendo ui datepicker without jQuery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview, kendo-mobile

i'm using Kendo ui and i use datepicker but i want to customize title (tooltip), exactly i want to change the text from 'togle calandar' to 'calendrier'

this is a photo of my componenet:

[my datepicker with tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FYz6.png)

can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a component provided exactly for that purpose called `kendo-timepicker-messages`.

In your case you use it like this:

```
<kendo-datepicker>
    <kendo-timepicker-messages toggle="calendrier"></kendo-timepicker-messages>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

You can set many other captions on the component. You can read more in the Kendo documentation for globalization [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/globalization/#toc-custom-messages).